# How to copy files from github to WASB storage in azure function

Tags: c#, azure, github, azure-storage, azure-functions

I want to copy files from github to wasb storage when any push is happened in github.

Is there any example azure function code to follow?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create and use a [GitHub webhook triggered function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-github-webhook-triggered-function#create-a-github-webhook-triggered-function) that is triggered by an HTTP webhook request.

In Azure Functions app code, you can extract github commits from request body `string data = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` and use [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/) to retrieve the contents of files within a repository.

Besides, to upload files to wasb storage, you can use client library ([Referencing assemblies in Azure Functions app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#referencing-external-assemblies)) or REST API.

Comment: I do not have sample, you can refer to the documentations that I provided and implement functionality based on your requirements.

Comment: I have using continuous deployment option in Azure function with Git-hub as source. So my git-hub repository files are stored in Kudu console. How can I copy files from D:\home\site\repository/myrepo to WASB storage? Is this a better approach instead of using Git-hub API?